# Design for a Testing system

Tags: mysql, database-design, testing

I want to redesign a part of my system. I got the following objects:

```
Site:
id  
Name

Site Version:
id
idSite
Name

Task:
id
idSite
Name

Test:
id
idTask
Name

TestResult:
idTest
idSiteVersion
dateStarted
dateEnded
result
```

### Two problems:

1. You can see that I have a circle in the definitions. The problem is, I got `Tasks` defined for `Sites`, and also through the `TestResult > SiteVersion > Site` I can get back to `Site` again.
2. The main query to answer is, for a given `Site`, show all `SiteVersion` and their compatibility to `Tasks` defined for them.

Comment: Could you please explain the problem(s) you see with #1.

Comment: i thought it was wrong at the time, but I understood later that it's ok @LeighRiffel

Comment: So basically there is no longer a question here.  If so, could you please close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved `2.` using [sub-querys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706228/design-for-db-when-needed-to-know-lastest-for-something/7722289#7722289)

```
SELECT
  tr1.id AS id,
  dsv.idSite_id AS idSite,
  tr1.idSiteVersion_id AS idSiteVersion,
  tr1.idTest_id AS idTest,
  tr1.result AS result,
  tr1.timeStarted AS timeStarted,
FROM 
  dash.testresult AS tr1 
  NATURAL JOIN (
    SELECT idTest_id, idSiteVersion_id, MAX(timeEnd) AS timeEnd
    FROM dash.testresult
    WHERE timeEnd IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY idTest_id, idSiteVersion_id
  ) AS tr2
  JOIN dash.siteversion AS dsv
    ON dsv.id = tr1.idSiteVersion_id
  JOIN dash.test AS dtest
    ON dtest.id = tr1.idTest_id AND dtest.ignored = 0
```